# Verb+subject+object sentence structure

Tags: sentence-structure

please help me with the grammar used in sentences mentioned below

1. Buy her medicine.
2. Find you the right partner.

what is the sentence structure used in these sentences? Give me more examples of the same structure if you have.

Please share your thoughts and clear my doubts.

Thank you.

Comment: The first is an imperative clauses where "medicine" is direct object and "her" is indirect object. The second one is odd; as written it can only be a subordinate clause (cf. "I will _find you the right partner_"). But if you change "you" to "yourself" then it too becomes an imperative with "the right partner" as direct object and "yourself" as  indirect object.

Comment: Btw, with imperative clauses the subject is usually omitted but understood as "you".

Answer (score 1):

"Buy her medicine" can mean "Purchase medicine for her" or "Purchase the medicine that she [makes and/or] sells".  Both are imperative sentences, in which the speaker or writer instructs or commands the person spoken to purchase medicine.  Just which meaning is the "correct" one take depends on the context and any preceding sentences, but I would normally say the first meaning I gave above is more likely than the second.

"Find you the right partner" could be a sentence, such as would normally be written "You find the right partner", but as it stands it appears to be a sentence fragment, the middle part of "I will try to find you the right partner to dance with."